Dockerizing PHP (Smarty) and SQLite3 Project
I’m trying to Dockerize my PHP (Smarty) and SQLite3 website but am encountering issues with my Dockerfile and Docker Compose configuration.
Currently, I could display both html and css with localhost:8000, but all parts that I wrote with PHP is displayed as plain text, which seems my dockerfile does not install the Smarty (and DB).
Here's a summary of my Dockerfile setup (I've trimmed it down to the essential parts):
dockerfile
Copy code
FROM php:8.2.0-apache

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzip-dev unzip curl sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_sqlite

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Copy project files
COPY ./templates ./templates
# ... other COPY commands

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Enable Apache mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

And here’s my compose.yaml file:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: corporate_site_web
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - corporate_site_network

networks:
  corporate_site_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-compose-volume:

I would appreciate any guidance on fixing my setup as I'm new to Docker and struggling to get it to work. Thank you!

You forgot to tell us what the issues are. It's hard to suggest a solution to a problem we know nothing about! Please [edit] your question. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks

If all parts that you wrote with PHP are displayed as plain text, then you didn't configure Apache to actually run PHP so: docker exec -it yourcontainername bash and find out what's in httpd.conf? Does it try to load libphp8-2? What do the Apache logs say? etc. (basically: get in your container and poke around a bit to see whether everything's set up the way you'd expect it to be)
